# Is it possible to show dummy text for Views in the IDEA Android UI designer?

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I've recently switched from eclipse to IntelliJ IDEA for Android development. I'm not missing any features, beside the rather helpful designer preview in eclipse. I populate certain views in my activities at runtime, there are no texts defined in the corresponding XML files. In eclipse, it looks like this:

[image]

It fills the empty views with placeholder text which is nice to get a rough impression of the layout without having to start the app. But in IDEA, the designer looks like this:

[image]

The views are empty, and it's difficult to even see them without selecting them in the Component Tree. I haven't found anything in the options, is this missing from IDEA or did I miss an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible right now, but it would be nice to have, I've created a new feature request, [please vote](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-105162).